# Type.InvokeMember when method has a Dictionary parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, dictionary, hashtable, invokemember

I am getting a

> Method 'MyNameSpace.MyClass.MyMethod' not found.

when I changed a parameter of `MyMethod` from `Hashtable` to `Dictionary<string, string>`.

The invoke call is

```
return = t.InvokeMember("MyMethod", (BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod), null, instance, params);
```

When I do

```
Type type = a.GetType(String.Concat(DLLName, ".MyClass"));
var methods = t.GetMethods();
```

`methods` contains `MyMethod()` so it is there.

Can anyone shed any light?

The `params` are

```
Object[] params = new Object[11];
...
params[5] = foo.myHashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);   
...
```

The MyMethod signature is

```
public MyMethodReturn MyMethod(Byte[] m, Hashtable d, Mutex mut, FileStream logFile, Hashtable t, Dictionary<string, Byte[]> fields, bool e, byte[] k, int hashCode, bool h, Byte[] mm)
```

Comment: `foo.myHashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);` doesn't actually put the dictionary anywhere - it just drops it on the floor for the garbage collector to deal with; did you assign this to a variable or anything? Better: can you show the *actual* code that *actually* calls `InvokeMember` with your inputs? And preferably the *actual* signature of `MyMethod` (because I have concerns about what may be lurking in the `...`)

Comment: I didn't copy & paste correctly. Edited. Okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
params[5] = foo.myHashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
               .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
```

This creates a `Dictionary<object,object>`, which does not match the signature. This is because a `DictionaryEntry` has `object Key {get;}` and `object Value {get;}`, and the compiler is using those to infer the types for the dictionary (generic type inference).

Try:

```
params[5] = foo.myHashtable.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
               .ToDictionary(d => (string)d.Key, d => (byte[])d.Value);
```

This will create a `Dictionary<string,byte[]>`, which should match.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection can not find the method because the method expects a hash table not a dictinary, dictionary doesn't inherit from hashtable so you can not use dictionary instead of hashtable. Method signiture should match before reflection can invoke a method.

Comment: from the question: "The MyMethod signature is `public MyMethodReturn MyMethod(... Dictionary<string, Byte[]> fields ...)`" - looks like a dictionary to me...

Comment: Yep, Sorry didn't notice it